# Bloquear landscape en un sitio web html5 para que se muetre unicamente en portrait

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Actualmente he creado un sitio web en HTML5, el problema es de que el sitio esta diseñado de tal manera que se muestre únicamente en orientación portrait, cuando se visualiza en dispositivos móviles se permite la rotación llevando el sitio a verse en landscape, lo que estoy necesitando es un código que me permita bloquear eso y mostrarlo únicamente de manera vertical, saludos.

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado por favor

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este codigo JS en el load de la página:

```
if (screen.lockOrientation) {
  screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
  //Registra evento evento para cambio de orientación
  screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
      console.log("Orientación cambiada ha: " + screen.orientation);
  });
}
```

Comment: en que parte tengo que agregar este fragmento de codigo